# Jest: test suite failed to run Error: No message was provided

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am converting existing tests to use typescript with ts-jest and I have everything finding all the files but all of the tests fail with the error

```
 FAIL  src/components/Buttons/__tests__/index.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Error: No message was provided
```

I have no idea what is going on and I can't seem to find anyone who had the same problem by Googling either, which is scary...

package.json with jest config

```
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfigFile": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.json",
        "babelConfig": {
          "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
        }
      }
    },
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts",
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "typeface-roboto|\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"
    ]
  },
```

example test file...

```
import React from 'react';

import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import Account from '../account';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  expect(shallow(<Account />)).toBe(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding a **tsconfig.json** file in my project directory fixed this issue.

My tsconfig.json file didn't need anything special in fact it didn't need anything at all! Simply having a blank tsconfig.json file allowed my tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

> I was getting similar error for 3 test suits and one was running perfectly. These were running before code merge. After investigation I found that My components are having AAD authentication and the configuration for the same were missing, which I removed for doing check-in. After adding correct configuration resolved my issue.

Comment: @Swapna I get the same error with AAD authentication. How did yo fix it?

Answer (score -1):

for some reason, having my tsconfig in the settings was causing the problem. I put it there even though it was the standard name and place (tsconfig.js in the project root)

as soon as I deleted this, I had more errors in my config to clear, but it got past the error in my question